# How to navigate HOC component to App component

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

[This is my folder structure image]
I have used aws-amplify HOC component for Authentication when user signin.I have used Terms and Condition link on signin screen but my terms & condition screen resides in main APP and my signin screen resides in HOC Component how can I navigate to terms & condition screen with out authentication. Can we make the custom states?

```
import React from 'react';
import {SignIn} from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import {
Text,
View,
TextInput,
TouchableHighlight,
Image,
Alert,
ScrollView,
TouchableOpacity,
Keyboard,
KeyboardAvoidingView,
TouchableWithoutFeedback, ActivityIndicator,
Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import {Auth, Hub} from 'aws-amplify';
import styles from './CustomSignIn.style.js';
export class CustomSignIn extends SignIn {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this._validAuthStates = ['signIn', 'signedOut', 'signedUp'];
this.state = {
  loading: false
};
Hub.listen('auth', (data) => {
  console.log('A new auth event has happened: ', data.payload.event);
  this.setState({
    loading: false,
  });
})
    
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={{color: "#000000"}}
            placeholderTextColor="#2C2D4D"
            placeholder="Password *"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            key="password"
            name="password"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({password: text})}
            value={this.state.password}
            required={true}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row-reverse', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{marginBottom:30}} onPress={() => super.changeState("forgotPassword")}>
            <Text style={{textAlign:'right', color:'#F40B0B', fontWeight:'bold'}}>FORGOT PASSWORD</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {
            this.state.error === 'User is not confirmed.' ? 
            <TouchableOpacity style={{marginBottom:30, }} onPress={() => 
              {
                super.changeState("confirmSignUp");
                this.setState({error:null})
              }
              }>
              <Text style={{textAlign:'left', color:'#F40B0B', fontWeight:'bold'}}>CONFIRM USER</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> :
            <></>
          }
          
        </View>
        <Text style={{color: 'red', paddingBottom: 10}}>
          {this.state.error}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonContainer}
          onPress={() => {
            if (
              this.state.username != null &&
              this.state.password != null &&
              this.state.username != '' &&
              this.state.password != ''
            ) {
              //Alert.alert("Credentials Required", "UserName"+this.state.username+" password:"+this.state.password)
              //Alert.alert("Log In:", this.state.password);
              this.setState({
                loading: true
              })
              super.signIn();
            } else {
              Alert.alert(
                'Credentials Required!',
                'Please enter Username and Password',
              );
            }
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOG IN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
        {/* <Text
          style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginBottom: 20, color: '#2C2D4D'}}>
          Or Sign-up with
        </Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{margin: 10}}
            onPress={() => {
              Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Google'});
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../../assets/google.png')}
              style={{height: 48, width: 55}}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
          
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{margin: 10}}
            onPress={() => {
              Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Facebook'});
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../../assets/facebook.png')}
              style={{height: 48, width: 55}}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View> */}
        <View style={styles.termsContainer}>
          <Text style={{color: '#2C2D4D',alignSelf:'center',marginBottom:5}}>By proceeding you also agree to the</Text>
           <Text style={{color: '#2C2D4D',alignSelf:'center',marginBottom:10}}>
                <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', color:'#F40B0B'}} onPress={() => super.changeState('Terms')}>Terms Of Service</Text> and <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', color:'#F40B0B'}}>Privacy Policy</Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Please show some code so we get general idea of what you are asking

Comment: @LeoOdishvili please check the last onpress for terms and condition,i have also used this.props.navigation.navigate(Terms) 
I have added the Terms in app navigator